# Multiple filters per column in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

This might sound like a stupid question but any help would be appreciated. I am trying to apply a filter on my RDD based on a date column.

```
val tran1 = sc
  .textFile("TranData.Dat")
  .map(_.split("\t"))
  .map(p => postran(
    p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5), p(6), p(7), p(8),
    p(9).toDouble, p(10).toDouble,p(11).toDouble))
```

I was able to apply a single date filter like below.

```
val tran = tran1.filter(x => x.PeriodDate == "2015-03-21 00:00:00.000")
```

How do I add more dates to this filter ? Is there a way I can read the comma separated date values in a variable and just pass that variable inside the filter() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL:

```
select * From Table where age in (25, 35, 45) and country in ("Ireland", "Italy")
```

can be written with the following Scala:

```
val allowedAges: Seq[Int] = Seq(25, 35, 45)
val allowedCountries: Seq[String] = Seq("Ireland", "Italy")
val result = table.filter(x => (allowedAges.contains(x.age) && allowedCountries.contains(x.country))
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick..Sorry jumped my guns early...I am looking for applying filter to the same column but with multiple date values....Something like

Comment: Something like PeriodDate in ( date1, date2, date3)

Comment: @Mjas something like filter(x=> x.contains(date1,date2,date3)) ? You could also do filter(x=> x > date && x < date)

Comment: Thanks...That works but for a range of Dates or any other attribute. i was looking for a way to pass different values which might not belong within a specific date

Comment: @Mjas I'm still not clear on what you mean.  I updated the answer but it may not be what you mean.  Can you write what you mena in pseudo code, does not matter if it  is does not compile?

Comment: Patrick - Here is what I need. You suggested two filter conditions on two different columns. I need to pass multiple filters on the same column which does not necessarily be a range (Hence < and > would not help)....For Example I need some thing like this SQL statement in Spark/Scala......Select * From Table where Table.Age in (25, 35, 45)..I should be able to pass similar filters to other columns as well....Thanks

Comment: Hi. The current answer would work for that SQL. Just make dates ages and use contains on the Seq